# Incompatible variable type issues

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I'm a newcomer to coding, having just picked up my first coding unit this year on Java, and for one of our programming projects, we've been tasked to take a number sequence and derive the polynomial used to create that sequence in terms of "x."

The following segment of code (is it a segment? I mean, it's bloody long) comes from a Term class, whose job is to output a single term of the polynomial, and is called by the methods within 2 other classes - Polynomial and Sequence. It is an updated version of another method, except this one refrains from outputting stuff like `x^1` in the place of `x`, `0x^3` in the place of `0`, `2x^0` in the place of `2`, etc. etc. etc.

Being a newbie to coding, my codes aren't exactly the prettiest thing you'll set your eyes on. Prepare yourselves for quite possibly the most disgusting piece of code you'll ever see:

`// this function returns the term as a String for display:
// see the sample file and the test program for the layout required`

```
public String displayImproved()
{
    if(coefficient > 1)
    {
        if (exponent <= 1)
        {
            if (exponent = 1)
            {
                return " +" + coefficient + "x";
            }
            else
            {
                return " +" + coefficient;
            }
        if (exponent = 0)
        {
            return " +" + coefficient + "x^" + exponent;
        }

        }
        if(coefficient = 1)
        {
            if (exponent <= 1)
            {
                if (exponent = 1)
                {
                    return " +" + "x";
                }
                else
                {
                    return " +" + "1";
                }
            }
            else
            {
               return " +" + "x^" + exponent;
            }
        }
    }
    if (coefficient = 0)
    {
        return "";
    }
    if (coefficient < 0)
    {
        if (exponent <= 1)
        {
            if (exponent = 1)
            {
                return coefficient + "x";
            }
            else
            {
                return coefficient;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return coefficient + "x^" + exponent;
        }
    }

}`
```

The sample file and test program I'm referring to can be found on the unit website: http://teaching.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS1001/projects/project1/, which also has the details of the project we've been set if you want to try it out!

The issue I have here, dirtiness of the code aside, is the stream of error messages I get when I try to compile - for example, the very first error message I get comes on the line `if (exponent = 1)` and it tells me "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean." For reference, the `exponent` variable is an integer, and the `coefficient` variable is a double. The program I'm using is BlueJ, if that helps. Not that I'm getting anywhere with my code soon!

**So why is BlueJ telling me that I'm trying to switch between variable types, and why is it not working?**

Comment: `if (coefficient = 0)` -> `if (coefficient == 0)` would be better :)

Comment: `x = 1` means assign 1 to x, `x == 1` means x identical to 1

Comment: Oh wow. Please tell me this is it :O

Comment: `if (coefficient = 0)` is not compilable in java.

Comment: Yep so that fixed it! However the issue I'm now getting is in the line `if (exponent == 0)` being flagged as "Unreachable code." What does that mean???

Comment: @NextTimeDW It means the method will return before it reaches this `if` statement, which it does. You have wrote one `if-else` and you are returning something in both of them, so the `if(exponent == 0)` line is never executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change all of **if (exponent = 1)** by **if (exponent == 1)**
Cause wih one = you assigne value and with 2 you check eguality

Answer (score -1):

When you use `=` it means set the value of `exponent` to 1.